# How to get correct white balance with different types of light sources?

Tags: white-balance, sunlight, indoor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I properly white-balance my photographs when I'm shooting in mixed-lighting environments?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8577/how-do-i-properly-white-balance-my-photographs-when-im-shooting-in-mixed-lightin)

I was at a wedding recently, and the reception hall had these huge windows that let a lot of sunlight through. The overhead lamps used inside the reception hall had a strong yellow tint to them. Given the two different types of light sources, "white" seems to have a vastly different definition in different parts of the photo. I found that a lot of my photos were near impossible to correct the white balance in post production (I shot in RAW).

Here is an example from the set I shot at the wedding:

[image]

If I set the white balance relative to something outdoors, everything inside looks too yellow (as seen). If I set the white balance relative to something indoors, everything that falls in the sunlight looks too blue. Neither looks particularly "good".

So, does anyone have tips for how to handle this sort of situation next time I take a shot? I'll also accept answers that offer post-processing advice.

// As an aside, I'm just an photography hobbyist...not a professional wedding photographer ;)

Comment: First you really better check your lens out - its got these weird black bars on it!