# How to Make Indoor Photography Not Blurry

Tags: canon, portrait, shutter-speed, indoor

I am a beginning photographer with a Canon Rebel XTI. I'm trying to get indoor portraits of my son, but I can't seem to get non-blurry photos because the shutter speed is too slow as I need to let the light in, however he is moving thus causing the blurriness. Whenever I change the shutter speed, the photos become too dark. If anyone has any tips, techniques or settings on the camera they could suggest that would be most appreciated. Maybe I need a different lens?

Thank you!

Comment: see also:   http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6250/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18962/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16011/15871

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much light you have, you can probably get good results with an f/1.8 lens.  I assume you're using the kit lens.

Otherwise, try flash.